# Why does MariaDB imports SQL faster than MySQL or Percona out of the box?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, percona

I recently installed a MySQL server on an Intel Xeon machine that has 32GB RAM and a 2TB HDD. As soon as I tried to import a SQL file that was generated on another server that runs MariaDB, I noticed that the import was taking too long.

I'm used to doing the same import on the MariaDB server with 16GB RAM in about 30 seconds; however, it took about 5 minutes on the newly installed MySQL server for the same import to complete.

The SQL file that I'm importing is not too large; just 50MB.

I removed MySQL from the new server and installed Percona and still, it took about 5 minutes to do the import.

I removed Percona and installed MariaDB and it took about 30 seconds to complete the import.

For business reasons, I need to use MySQL or Percona. I'm not allowed to use MariaDB for this project.

I can understand differences of a few seconds between MySQL, Percona and MariaDB but I can only imagine that there is a setting that is configured on MariaDB out of the box that is not right on MySQL or Percona.

Note, I didn't make any changes to my.cnf files. This is out of the box.

The mysqldump command that I'm using to produce the SQL file is:

```
mysqldump -u $UNAME -p $DBNAME --add-drop-table --single-transaction
 | gzip > $BACKUPDIR/$FNAME.sql.gz
```

Any suggestions to make the SQL import on MySQL or Percona as fast as MariaDB?

EDIT:

MySQL

```
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_log_file_size    50331648
```

MariaDB

```
+----------------------------------+
| @@version                        |
+----------------------------------+
| 10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+----------------------------------+
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_log_file_size    50331648
```

Comment: I'd compare the innodb configuration options in effect in each version. For example, if MariaDB defaults to a larger `innodb_buffer_pool_size` or larger `innodb_log_file_size`, it could help speed up imports. Run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` in each instance and save to a file, then diff the files.

Comment: Also double-check that MariaDB is creating your tables as InnoDB. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`. Bulk-loads to MyISAM tables are likely to run faster, but that's not a good reason to use MyISAM.

Comment: You should include in your question above the specific version of each software package you use. Get this with `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: I added the versions of MySQL and MariaDB to the original post. Again, nothing has been configured on these two servers. They are exactly as they get installed out of the box. I don't have Percona installed at the moment.

Comment: 128M is to small for the buffer_pool.  Use about 70% of RAM.  (This is not likely to address the Question.)

Comment: Is it the same dump file?  Are the rest of the `innodb%` `VARIABLES` the same?

Comment: I'll try with a different hardware and I'll report back. Thank you for your help!